# OleDbCommand syntax error 0x80040E14 in SELECT Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbdataadapter

This query runs perfectly in Access 2010:

```
SELECT te.[EnterpirseName], COUNT(to.[ID]) AS Orgs, SUM(to.[Members]) AS Mems
FROM tbl_Enterprise AS te, tbl_Organizations AS to
WHERE to.[Enterprise_ID] = te.[ID] AND te.[Status] = 1
GROUP BY te.[EnterpirseName]
```

However when I try to execute it from my `C#` winforms application, I get syntax error:

0x80040E14 `Syntax error near keyword FROM`

**EDIT:** My C# code:

```
string strCommand = "SELECT te.[EnterpirseName], COUNT(to.[ID]) AS Orgs, SUM(to.[Members]) AS Mems" +
    " FROM tbl_Enterprise AS te, tbl_Organizations AS to" +
    " WHERE to.[Enterprise_ID] = te.[ID]" +
    " AND te.[Status] = 1" +
    " GROUP BY te.[EnterpirseName]";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnString))
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strCommand, conn);

    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

That's how `strCommand` looks like in Debug:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I execute the same query in Access and it runs fine.

Comment: Your c# code where this is called will help

Comment: add C# code also.

Comment: you could try using [] for table names also..

Comment: @akhilkumar still the same error

Comment: Why `" FROM tbl_Enterprise AS te, tbl_Organizations AS to" +` ?You have to use joins for two tables

Comment: In debug; what do you see as strCommand? Seems to me as some typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO is a reserved word in Access as well. Try to replace it to something like `tbl_Org`.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure your c# app isn't using another engine, like SQL Server? In SQL Server, TO is a reserved word, so you should use [To] instead.

Comment: My whole application works with only one DB that is in Access.